# Accessing curl executable from Program files?

Tags: windows, permissions, wsh

I have built an application which uses user executable through WScript com object.
Now the main program is located in C:\Program files\Myapp
Curl executable is located in C:\Curl
But it looks like my application is unable to execute curl if main application is in Program files.
If i move it to another location it can execute curl nicely.
Problem occurs only on Windows Xp on Vista and Win7 it works perfectly.
Is there any special permissions i have to give to my app or what?

Comment: When you say it "cannot execute" it, what do you mean? Do you get an error message, andif so, what is it?

Comment: I don't get any error messages. It just looks like if program is installed into program files. Then its not allowed to read or write to another locations.
Actually structure is simple 
1. Main application is installed into program files 
2. External resources like database which need's to be writeable will be installed into application data.

Database will be created by program. But looks like it's unable to create it on Xp. It works Ok with same structure on Vista and 7 but not on Xp.

Comment: Hm actually it turns out that it's not read and write problem cause database will be greated correctly.
It just looks like im unable to run curl.exe through wscript shell.

Answer (score 0):

Oh got it finally sorted out.
Actually everything was fine just missed that on Xp there is spaces between in path's just needed to add double quotes to my command and done.